# More elegant way to make a C++ member function change different member variables based on template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, dry

Today, I wrote some code that needed to add elements to different container variables depending on the type of a template parameter.  I solved it by writing a friend helper class specialized on its own template parameter which had a member variable of the original class.  It saved me a few hundred lines of repeating myself without adding much complexity.  However, it seemed kludgey.  I would like to know if there is a better, more elegant way.

The code below is a greatly simplified example illustrating the problem and my solution.  It compiles in g++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace myNS{

  template<class Elt>
  struct Container{
    std::vector<Elt> contents;
    template<class Iter>
    void set(Iter begin, Iter end){
      contents.erase(contents.begin(), contents.end());
      std::copy(begin, end, back_inserter(contents));
    }
  };


  struct User;

  namespace WkNS{
    template<class Elt>
    struct Worker{
      User& u;

      Worker(User& u):u(u){}

      template<class Iter>
      void set(Iter begin, Iter end);
    };
  };

  struct F{ int x; explicit F(int x):x(x){} };
  struct G{ double x; explicit G(double x):x(x){} };

  struct User{
    Container<F> a;
    Container<G> b;

    template<class Elt>
    void doIt(Elt x, Elt y){
      std::vector<Elt> v; v.push_back(x); v.push_back(y);
      Worker<Elt>(*this).set(v.begin(), v.end());
    }

  };


  namespace WkNS{
    template<class Elt> template<class Iter>
    void Worker<Elt>::set(Iter begin, Iter end){
      std::cout << "Set a." << std::endl;
      u.a.set(begin, end);
    }

    template<> template<class Iter>
    void Worker<G>::set(Iter begin, Iter end){
      std::cout << "Set b." << std::endl;
      u.b.set(begin, end);
    }
  };

};

int main(){
  using myNS::F; using myNS::G;
  myNS::User u;
  u.doIt(F(1),F(2));
  u.doIt(G(3),G(4));
}
```

`User` is the class I was writing.

`Worker` is my helper class.  I have it in its own namespace because I don't want it causing trouble outside myNS.

`Container` is a container class whose definition I don't want to modify, but is used by `User` in its instance variables.

`doIt<F>` should modify a. `doIt<G>` should modify b.

`F` and `G` are open to limited modification if that would produce a more elegant solution.  (As an example of one such modification, in the real application `F`'s constructor takes a dummy parameter to make it look like `G`'s constructor and save me from repeating myself.)

In the real code, `Worker` is a friend of `User` and member variables are private.  To make the example simpler to write, I made everything public.  However, a solution that requires things to be public really doesn't answer my question.

Given all these caveats, is there a better way to write `User::doIt`?

Comment: Why don't you just have a non-template `User::doIt` member function overloaded for `F` and for `G`?

Comment: The real `User::doIt` is complex (it does pre-calculation for a multidimensional interpolation routine) and does almost the same thing to a and to b, the main difference being the using the appropriate member functions of F and G objects.  The template avoids copy/paste repeating the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Emile Cormier's comment, I thought of a way to both keep from repeating myself and to also eliminate the `Worker` class: make two trivial non-template `doIt` functions for `F` and `G` and have each call a third templated `doIt` function with the variable to change passed as a parameter.  Here is the modified code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace myNS{

  template<class Elt>
  struct Container{
    std::vector<Elt> contents;
    template<class Iter>
    void set(Iter begin, Iter end){
      contents.erase(contents.begin(), contents.end());
      std::copy(begin, end, back_inserter(contents));
    }
  };

  struct F{ int x; explicit F(int x):x(x){} };
  struct G{ double x; explicit G(double x):x(x){} };

  struct User{
    Container<F> a;
    Container<G> b;

    template<class Elt>
    void doIt(Elt x, Elt y, Container<Elt>& cont, const char*name){
      std::vector<Elt> v; v.push_back(x); v.push_back(y);
      cont.set(v.begin(), v.end());
      std::cout << "Set " << name << std::endl;
    }

    void doIt(F x, F y){ doIt(x,y,a,"a"); }

    void doIt(G x, G y){ doIt(x,y,b,"b"); }

  };

}

int main(){
  using myNS::F; using myNS::G;
  myNS::User u;
  u.doIt(F(1),F(2));
  u.doIt(G(3),G(4));
}
```